# Elm tree trimmed to much!

Tags: trees

My elm tree was "trimmed" they took down almost all but the top 1/3 of the branches. Will they branches grow back? How can I help the tree grow new ones? How long would it take to fill in again?

Comment: Elm trees are unusual in North America after Dutch Elm disease ran it's course.  Can you tell us where the trees are and provide a photo?

Comment: @kevinskio - Kind of depends on the elm. We have slippery elms and (yuck) siberian elms here, and there are cultivars like Frontier and Valley Forge in my city. We also have one lone American Elm that has an 8 FOOT caliper, so it has to be immune to DED.

Comment: @Jurp lucky, the only elm we had nearby was a rock elm and got blown over in a storm

Comment: Why was it trimmed? What was it interfering with?